# Execute sql query to update text file with VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba, text-files, adodb

I am building an excel application that uses .txt files as small databases. My "select" function works fine, but I am struggling to build the "update" function. I am getting runtime error

> "-2147467259 (80004005)". The reference "Microsoft ActiveX Data
>   Objects 6.1 Object Library" is selected.

Any advice? Thanks!

```vb
Sub UpdateTextFileData()

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, strFolder As String, sqlquery As String

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

    strFolder = 'local folder path 

    cn.Open "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};" & _
        "Dbq=" & strFolder & ";" & _
        "Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;" & "ReadOnly=False;"

    sqlquery = "UPDATE banco.txt SET ColunaC = '12345' WHERE ColunaB = 'GGGGG'"

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    Set rs = cn.Execute(sqlquery)

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Database (dummy):

```
| ColunaA | ColunaB | ColunaC              |
|---------|---------|----------------------|
| 1       | AAAAA   | 5.20938877975815E-02 |
| 2       | BBBBBB  | .237499095717172     |
| 3       | CCCCCC  | .377185643907512     |
| 4       | DDDDD   | .518159496941826     |
| 5       | EEEEEE  | .116719215855864     |
| 6       | FFFFFF  | .509676881331012     |
| 7       | GGGGG   | .214284738946508     |
| 8       | HHHHH   | .897400886023718     |
```

Comment: Eduardo, you need to give us steps to reproduce what you're trying to do. Could you provide us (as plain text in the question!) sample data for the text file that works with the code? And I assume you have a reference (Tools/References) to the ADO library mentioned in the error message? Anything else we should know about in order to test this? Do you have some ADO code that does work with text files (just so we can see it)?

Comment: Also, be careful about posting information that could allow others to attack your system (file path!) You can use the [edit] link below the question to change the question content but be aware this does *not* remove it from the Stack Overflow database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL is really for databases, not text files.  You can easily do a find/replace, as described below.

```vb
Sub ReplaceStringInFile()

    Dim sBuf As String
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim iFileNum As Integer
    Dim sFileName As String

    ' Edit as needed
    sFileName = "C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\test.txt"

    iFileNum = FreeFile
    Open sFileName For Input As iFileNum

    Do Until EOF(iFileNum)
        Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
        sTemp = sTemp & sBuf & vbCrLf
    Loop
    Close iFileNum

    sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "THIS", "THAT")

    iFileNum = FreeFile
    Open sFileName For Output As iFileNum
    Print #iFileNum, sTemp
    Close iFileNum

End Sub
```

Or, import the data into Excel, make any/all required changes in the sheet, and save the data back to a text file.  The worksheet could be a very intuitive front-end GUI for your 'database'.  Use the code below to do this exact thing.  Of course, there are many alternatives to this specific solution, so always keep an open mind when doing these kinds of things.

```vb
Sub OpenMe()

FName = "C:\your_path\test.txt"
Sep = ","

Dim RowNdx As Long
Dim ColNdx As Integer
Dim TempVal As Variant
Dim WholeLine As String
Dim Pos As Integer
Dim NextPos As Integer
Dim SaveColNdx As Integer

'disable screen updates
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'error handling
On Error GoTo EndMacro

'Importing data starts from the selected cell in a worksheet
SaveColNdx = ActiveCell.Column
RowNdx = ActiveCell.Row

'open the file in read mode
Open FName For Input Access Read As #1

'Read the file until End of Line
While Not EOF(1)
    'read line by line
    Line Input #1, WholeLine
    If Right(WholeLine, 1) <> Sep Then
        WholeLine = WholeLine & Sep
    End If
    ColNdx = SaveColNdx
    Pos = 1
    NextPos = InStr(Pos, WholeLine, Sep)
    'finding each column data
    While NextPos >= 1
        TempVal = Mid(WholeLine, Pos, NextPos - Pos)
        Cells(RowNdx, ColNdx).Value = TempVal
        Pos = NextPos + 1
        ColNdx = ColNdx + 1
        NextPos = InStr(Pos, WholeLine, Sep)
    Wend
    RowNdx = RowNdx + 1
Wend

Close #1
Exit Sub
EndMacro:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox Err.Description, vbOKOnly, "Error"
Close #1

End Sub
```

Make your update(s) in the worksheet, then save the change(s).

```vb
Sub SaveAndCloseMe()

    Dim xRet As Long
    Dim xFileName As Variant
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
    xFileName = "C:\your_path\test.txt"
    If xFileName = False Then Exit Sub
    If Dir(xFileName) <> "" Then
        xRet = MsgBox("File '" & xFileName & "' exists.  Overwrite?", vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "Kutools for Excel")
        If xRet <> vbYes Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Kill xFileName
        End If
    End If
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs xFileName, xlUnicodeText
    If ActiveWorkbook.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    End If
My_Exit:
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: A simple replace from text "A" to text "B" is not exactly what I am looking for. I need something more complex to change data with some paralel conditions. Thank you anyway for you time

Comment: When one part of a query is not updateable, none of the query is updateable. Text files cannot be directly updated, like records in a database. Text files can be written and they can be appended to (add records to the end) but records cannot be updated or deleted.  I just changed my answer to import the data, make the change, and then save the change, just like I said initially.